# Can vaccines cause side effects that the virus itself will not cause?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination

The COVID vaccines have reignited the discussion about vaccines’ potential side effects. While we all know these are extremely rare, I would like to understand how they are even possible at all. A vaccine works by tricking the body into thinking that there is a viral attack, therefore how can we have any side effect at all aside from potentially the same ones that the disease itself, albeit in much more serious form, would cause to the organism?

Comment: Have you already looked into general side effects like local soreness? Have you looked into all the ingredients like carriers that are in the shot? Show your research so far.

Answer (score 0):

1. I assume the SEs you mentioned here are severe allergic reaction to COVID vaccine ( moderna + Pfizer ). People have different allergic rxn with different severities. Most commonly seen allergic rxns are type I sensitivity which leads to hives, narrowed airways etc.
2. Most people experience very short term reactions to the 2nd or 1st dose of Pfizer + modern a vaccine such as fever, chills, back pain because of the immune response those mRNA vaccines elicit. That means that your body learned how to response to the specific viral spike proteins properly.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. We work differently to many SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Unreferenced claims can be challenged and lead to deletion of your answer.